# How to find fibonancci series through recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion

For finding fibonanci series , i write this code:

```
def fib(n):
    if n ==1 or n ==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

this is absolutely ok. But my question is if i call fib() by fib(5) then how many times does it compute the value fib(2) ? And how ?

*sorry for the silly question, i am newer in programming*

Comment: A `print('computing', n)` at the start of your function gives you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As polku mentioned in the comments, it's simple enough to see how many times your function is being called:

```
def fib(n):
    print('Called fib({})'.format(n))
    if n ==1 or n ==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

>>> fib(5)
Called fib(5)
Called fib(4)
Called fib(3)
Called fib(2)
Called fib(1)
Called fib(0)
Called fib(1)
Called fib(2)
Called fib(1)
Called fib(0)
Called fib(3)
Called fib(2)
Called fib(1)
Called fib(0)
Called fib(1)
8
```

Your function knows nothing of any of its previous runs, so each time you ask it for a particular value (other than 0 or 1), it has to calculate it all over again. If you want to avoid that, you can use a process called *memoization*. An easy way to do that in Python is to exploit a common newbie gotcha, [the mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument):

```
def fib2(n, memo=[1, 1]):
    print('Called fib2({})'.format(n))
    if len(memo) > n:
        print('   I already know this one!')
        return memo[n]
    else:
        memo.append(fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2))
        return memo[-1]

>>> fib2(5)
Called fib2(5)
Called fib2(4)
Called fib2(3)
Called fib2(2)
Called fib2(1)
   I already know this one!
Called fib2(0)
   I already know this one!
Called fib2(1)
   I already know this one!
Called fib2(2)
   I already know this one!
Called fib2(3)
   I already know this one!
8
```

Each call of the function uses the same `memo` list object, so appending to it in one call will carry over to future calls.

Comment: Glad to see someone gave an example of memoization. +1

Answer (score 1):

you can use mutable types like lists and dicts

```
dict_counts = {}
def fib(n,d):
    v = d.get(n,0)
    d[n]=v+1
    if n ==1 or n ==0:
       return 1
    else:
       return fib(n-1,d) + fib(n-2,d)
fib(5, dict_counts)
print "all counts: ", dict_counts
print "count of f(2) = ", dict_counts.get(2, 0)
```

output:

```
all counts: {0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1}
count of f(2) = 3
```

dict is a mutable object so you can change values of dict inside the function and access the changes outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

> If I call fib(5) then how many times does it compute the value fib(2)?

Three. You can see for yourself if you add a print statement.

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        print('Computing fib(%i)...' % n)
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

The output will look like this:

```
In [4]: fib(5)
Computing fib(5)...
Computing fib(4)...
Computing fib(3)...
Computing fib(2)...
Computing fib(2)...
Computing fib(3)...
Computing fib(2)...
Out[4]: 8
```

This also gives you some idea of the internal structure of the recursion.

To figure out `fib(5)`, it has to `return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`, which is `fib(4) - fib(3)`. It has to compute `fib(4)` first.

To figure out `fib(4)`, it needs `fib(3)` and `fib(2)`. It does `fib(3)` first.

To figure out `fib(3)`, it does `fib(2)` and `fib(1)`. It does `fib(2)` first.

To figure out `fib(2)`, it needs `fib(1)` and `fib(0)`. It does `fib(1)` first.

Finally, we return without another function call! `fib(1)` gives us an integer 1 and we can get back to adding to `fib(0)`, which also immediately returns 1.

That addition completes the return of `fib(2)`. Remember this call was part of figuring out `fib(3)`, so now we need the last half of that addition. It is `fib(1)` so we return immediately and complete the call.

Then we can figure out the last half of `fib(3)`, which means we compute `fib(2)` again. Both parts of this immediately return and we get the answer.

Now we're back out in `fib(4)`. The first part of it has returned so we need to compute the next half, which is `fib(3)`. This is computed exactly as before.

Hopefully now the stack of `Computing fib(n)...` makes a bit more sense. :)

Comment: This ans is great for me to understand. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

`fib(2)` is calculated 3 times:

```
>>> fib(5)
computing fib(5)
computing fib(4)
computing fib(3)
computing fib(2)
computing fib(2)
computing fib(3)
computing fib(2)
8
```

To avoid this duplicate work, you can take an iterative approach to computing the *n*th Fibonacci number or implement memoization along with your recursion.

Answer (score 0):

it is more than once to compute each number and python is very week on recursion.
if you pass 5 to recursion code you have, it would calculate 5 times fib(1), 3 times fib(2), 2 times fib(3), and 1 time fib(4)/fib(5)

faster way to find fib

```
def fib(n):
...     a, b = 0, 1
...     for _ in xrange(n):
...         a, b = b, a+b
...     return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid recalculation is to use dynamic programming. You can save the amounts you calculate once in a list, and every time you want to calculate something, look for it in the list first. If you have it there you won't call the function again. 
You can also put a counter when accessing that list to find out how many times it accesses that.
Drawing the execution tree can also help:

for a number n steps will be:

1. (n-1, n-2)
2. (n-2, n-3), (n-3, n-4)
3. (n-3, n-4), (n-4, n-5), (n-4, n-5), (n-5, n-6)

and so on.

Comment: through the recurtion tree , i got the ans. Thanks .